# Concat of 2 excel cells of formatted text which can keep the formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to have a cell (A1) that is the exact concatonation of two source text cells (A2 and A3). The two source cells are simple text with SOME of the text in bold, underlined and of different font colours. How can I have the single target cell? When I use the formula in A1 of `**=A2 & A3**` it loses all the source text formatting.

Comment: There's always a chance to learn something new for my own, but I say thats not possible (without VBA).

Comment: nixda, Thanks, I fear you might be right... but that is a beast I haven't worked with - so not sure how to proceed. Let's see if someone has a magic rabbit they can pull out of the hat...

Answer (score 0):

This can kinda be done using a picture link. If you do not actually need text that is editable in A1 you can simply copy the source cell and then on the Home tab on the far left there is the Clipboard options. Click the small down arrow under Paste and at the very bottom there is a As Picture option. Hover over that and select from the right Paste as Picture link.

Picture link will then paste a box with the extact replica of what is the source cell. This also means that when you change the source cell at all, formatting or text the picture link will also change. If you want to concatanate I would just align left the first source cell and align right the second source cell and then paste two picture links over top of one another.

This may not be exactly what you are needing but if you just need to display info this will work.

A few pro tips:

When moving a picture around excel Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> then when you move it with your mouse it will snap to every cell boundary.

Another tip is if you remove the gridlines from your workbook (found in the View Tab there is a Grinlines check box) this will remove that faint gray border from the picture link. if strange bubbles or lines show up in the picture link try move the source cell and then back again. It just might need an update.

Pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]